# What's wrong in this recursive algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming, memoization

Problem statement:

An N-element permutation is an N-element sequence of distinct numbers from the set {1, 2, ...,n}. For example the sequence 2,1,4,5,3 is a 5-element permutation. P is an N-element permutation. Your task is to sort P in ascending order. But because it is very simple, I have a new rule for you. You have two sequences P and Q. P is an N-element permutation and Q is initially empty and formed by sorting P (i.e. finally Q = 1, 2, 3,... , N). You have to implement N steps to sort P. In the i-th step, P has N-i+1 remaining elements, Q has i-1 elements and you have to choose some x-th element (from the N-i+1 available elements) of P and put it to the left or to the right of Q. The cost of this step is equal to x * i. The total cost is the sum of costs of individual steps. After N steps, Q must be an ascending sequence. Your task is to minimize the total cost.

Input

The first line of the input file is T (T ≤ 10), the number of test cases. Then descriptions of T test cases follow. The description of each test case consists of two lines. The first line contains a single integer N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000). The second line contains N distinct integers from the set {1, 2, .., N}, the N-element permutation P.

Output

For each test case your program should write one line, containing a single integer - the minimum total cost of sorting.

Input:
1
4
4 1 3 2

Output:
15

My solution :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int sz;
int n[1001];
map<int,int>pos;
int solve(int i,int a,int b){
if(a==-1&&b==sz) //if all the elements have been moved 
    return 0;
if(i>sz)
    return INT_MAX;
    int ret = INT_MAX;
    if(a>=0) //select the element from left
        ret = min(ret,solve(i+1,a-1,b)+((i+1)*pos[n[a]]));
    if(b<sz) //select the element from right
        ret = min(ret,solve(i+1,a,b+1)+((i+1)*pos[n[b]]));
return ret;
}

int main()
{
   int t;
   cin>>t;
   while(t--){
        cin>>sz;
   for(int i=0;i<sz;i++){
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    n[i] = x; //value
    pos[x] = i+1; //position of elements of array before sorting
   }
   sort(n,n+sz); //sorting the array
   int ret = INT_MAX;
   for(int i=0;i<sz;i++)  
     ret= min(ret,solve(0,i,i+1));
             cout << ret << endl;

        }
    return 0;
}
```

This returns wrong answer . What's wrong with my approach ? How can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you are computing the cost based on pos[n[a]].

pos[n[a]] returns the position in the original array, but the cost should be based on the position in the current array P (i.e. with some elements moved to Q).

For example, if P is originally {4,1,2} then the position of the 2 is x==3, but after P is reduced to {1,2}, then the position of the 2 is x==2.

Comment: How can I fix this ?